# Symfony2 include PHPQRGenerator

Tags: php, symfony, qr-code

I am using Symfony2 and I want to use PHPQRGenerator library ( http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/ ) to generator QR Codes and display them on a page.

I don't know where I should put the PHP QR library, I tried following this tutorial [here](http://www.kiwwito.com/article/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2) but that didn't seem to work.

Keeps saying

```
"PHPQRGenerator_PHPQRGenerator" not found in Class/../../ on line 48.
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you use Symfony 2.0 or Symfony 2.1?

Comment: I am using Symfony version 2.1.2

Comment: Then use composer to set up your library. See getcomposer.org for more info. And accept more answers, 25% is way too low!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've found a solution in the meantime.

I did my qrCode generation with the qrCode package from aferrandini https://github.com/aferrandini/PHPQRCode. It imports the (original) phpqrcode-Library.

In your Symfony2 project, you can now use e.g.

```
\PHPQRCode\QRcode::png("Test", "/tmp/qrcode.png", 'L', 4, 2);
```

to create your qrCode.